# Setting a parameter in stored procedure raises an error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a `stored_procedure` using the following `sql` code:

```
INSERT INTO users (name,surname,email,phone,address_id)
VALUES (name,surname,email,phone,address_id);

SET @GeneratedUserID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO user_login (username,password_salt,hash_code,users_user_id)
VALUES (username,password_salt,hash_code,@GeneratedUserID );

INSERT INTO user_roles (user_id,role_id)
VALUES (@GeneratedUserID ,1);
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @GeneratedUserID = LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT INTO user_login (username,pas' at line 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely haven't changed the delimiter, but can't tell for sure, because you didn't post the whole code (please always do this). Therefore MySQL thinks, that the procedure is finished after the first `;`.

Your procedure should look like this:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure x(in p_param1 int, in p_param2 int)
begin
    statement1;
    statement2;
end$$
delimiter ;
```

Also note, that you should choose parameter names that are not the same as column names. Best practice is to use a prefix like `p_`. Same for variables. Use a prefix like `v_` or something.

Comment: Thank you! I had to include begin - end statements.